# how to use special expression using preg_match_all in php

Tags: php, preg-match, preg-match-all

I want to `preg_match_all()` this:

```
    if(isset($matches[1])){
        return $matches[1];
    }else{
        return false;
    }
}
$lines = file('jason.txt');
$i=0;
foreach ($lines as $line_num => $line) {
    $str_arr = getInbetweenStrings('"Vehicle":', ',"Buyer":', $line);
    echo '<pre>';
    print_r($str_arr);
}
```

Comment: The string is `"Vehicle": "1992 Macho Camry CE"`?

Comment: show how do you invoke  `getInbetweenStrings` function

Comment: It is in a array "QuoteRequestId": 343816132,
  "Vehicle": "1992 Macho Camry CE",
  "Buyer": "Carolina Auto Body",

Comment: If you start with json somewhere up the line, you'd better parse that instead.

Comment: unclear, show more code with those `$start, $end, $str` arguments values

Comment: and what are the values?

Comment: @BhriguDash  What is the status of your quesition?  Did either of the answers below solve your issue?  If so, please award one of them the green tick.  If not, please update your question to explain what is not being satisfied by the current answers.

Comment: @mickmackusa it does not worked i have parsed it through jquery

Comment: @BhriguDash It is unclear what you mean.  Are you saying the current list of answers didn't help and you solved it yourself using jquery?  Or are you still looking for a solution?  If you are still looking to manipulate the data using `php` and `preg_match_all` please update your question to provide sample input data and the expected output using the input data.  I will help you.

Comment: @mickmackusa actually the json format is not correct so it is used to parse through jquery and then decoded by php

Comment: @BhriguDash Is your issue resolved? or is there still something to fix?  Can you update your question with a sample string? If you have already solved it please provide an answer.  All questions on SO should come to some sort of resolution.  I will help if there is still something to do.

Comment: @BhriguDash Can you please update or delete your question so that it is not an information deadend for SO readers?  I would like to help if there is still something to fix.

Comment: @mickmackusa i have solved it by parsing through getting the object through jquery.

Comment: @BhriguDash Then it seems your question will be forever doomed to be "abandoned / unanswered".  When future readers come to this page looking for a php solution they will not know if either of the answers provided are functional/successful and readers won't know what you did to solve your issue.

Answer (score 0):

If the string is:

```
"Vehicle": "1992 Macho Camry CE"
```

Here is the regex:

```
preg_match_all("/: \"?([\w ]+)/", $str, $matches,  PREG_PATTERN_ORDER);
```

Then call

```
print_r($matches);
```

Which will return:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => : "1992 Macho Camry CE
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => 1992 Macho Camry CE
        )

)
```

To get the string, use:

```
$phrase = $matches[1];
```

**edit:**
Because of the source data is a json string, use the [json_decode](http://php.net/json_decode) function to convert all data in array:

```
$str = '[{"Vehicle": "1992 Macho Camry CE"}, {"Vehicle": "2017 OtherCar"}]';
$vehicles = json_decode($str, true);
print_r($vehicles);

Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [Vehicle] => 1992 Macho Camry CE
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [Vehicle] => 2017 OtherCar
        )
)
```

Comment: mmm initially the data which type is? Json? String? Or already array?

Comment: In this case, i suggest you to use `json_decode` that creates an array with all its elements.

Comment: Json is txt format but with some characters like { } and [ ] to recognize the datas. What specifically you are asking for?

Answer (score 0):

Based on your comment you are parsing a json file.

In that case you should not use regexes or string functions. Instead you should parse the json file directly.

To get it all in a multi-dimensional array structure:

```
$array = json_decode(file_get_contents('path/to/file.json'), true);
```

Comment: let me send u d file.

Comment: @BhriguDash json is human-readable text. As long as the contents of the text file make for a valid json string, you can parse it just fine.

Comment: @BhriguDash You should add the contents of the file to your question if you are unsure about it.

Comment: it is a big file how can i send u

Comment: @BhriguDash No, just paste the contents in a json validator to see if it is valid json.

Comment: it is a valid json if i covert it online but i cant do this everytime.can i have your mail id i will send u the file

Comment: can i have your mail id i will send u the file

Comment: @BhriguDash I don't care about your json file. If it is valid json, php can parse it and if it is big, just parse it once and store the results in the database.